# Stream Android camera as H264 mpeg-ts over UDP using GStreamer

Tags: android, udp, gstreamer, h.264, mpeg

I don't have much experience with gstreamer, and I couldn't find something online to figure it out.

I'm using [this open-source](https://git.collabora.com/cgit/user/joykim/gst-camera-test.git) to develop an Android app to stream camera as H264 mpegts over UDP.

I got stuck with the pipeline, where I have two working pipelines I just can't merge to work together.
The original opensource's pipeline :

```
"ahcsrc ! queue ! glimagesink name=vsink sync=false"
```

(when ahcsrc stands for android-hardware-camera-src)

And my tests pipeline :

```
"videotestsrc ! decodebin ! x264enc bframes=2 ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=192.168.102.74 port=1234"
```

Both works perfectly fine.

My goal is to take my test pipeline, and switch the videotestsrc to the ahcsrc as in:

```
"ahcsrc ! decodebin ! x264enc bframes=2 ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=192.168.102.74 port=1234"
```

Unfortunately no luck there. Would really appreciate any kind of help !

Edit:
I tried to add logs everywhere, and then saw there are no errors, except that every module changed it's status from PAUSED to PLAYING except the udpsink.

I added to it "udpsink async=false" which made it become PLAYING, yet no packet sent and no noticeable errors.
Maybe the sink doesn't get any data ?

Edit2: After trying everything I could have found it think it might be a problem with the ahcsrc, as this pipeline :

```
ahcsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! videoconvert.....
```

result with

> Could not link ahcsrc0 to videoconvert0

After all, it is part of the gst-plugins-bad. Any confimation would be great.

Answer (score -1):

What you mean no luck? any error?

The output from ahcsrc seem to be [raw yuv](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/docs/plugins/inspect/plugin-androidcamera.xml?h=1.8) - maybe there is no need to use decodebin, just videoconvert.

You can add queue after src for better performance, not sure if it will work, but this is it:

```
ahcsrc ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc bframes=2 ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=192.168.102.74 port=1234
```

Please add some logs with running your app with env variable `GST_LAUNCH=4 ./your-app` and paste them somewhere..

Comment: Tried to run your pipeline. I recieved this error:
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle: assertion 'GST_IS_VIDEO_OVERLAY (overlay)' failed

Comment: my pipe was not tested .. so maybe there is something wrong .. but why would any of my pipe's element produce this error - this looks like you are using some video sinks - do you? please add some more logs with this pipe - ideally in your question (other people will notice when you update your question) .. you can use pastebin and copy paste important parts